# Or en parámetros estáticos en método de Controller con Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Estoy intentando hacer un OR en la URL de una petición, pero no se si es posible o hay manera de hacerlo. En la documentacion [oficial](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) no dice nada de ello. Aquí el ejemplo de lo que estoy intentando:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/archivo|documento/{loquesea}")
 public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getValores(@PathVariable String archivoODocumento,@PathVariable String loquesea)
 {
  if (archivoODocumento.equals("archivo"){
    //cosas de archivo
  }else{
   //cosas de documento
  }
   //cosas comunes
 }
```

Pero lo que si dice la API, es que se puede hacer esto

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/archivo/{loquesea}")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/documento/{loquesea}")
 public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getValores(@PathVariable String archivoODocumento,@PathVariable String loquesea)
 {
  if (archivoODocumento.equals("archivo"){
    //cosas de archivo
  }else{
   //cosas de documento
  }
   //cosas comunes
 }
```

Pero claro, ¿cómo controlo en ese caso, si la variable es "archivo" o "documento"?

Ideas, sugerencias o comentarios son bienvenidos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien por qué lo quieres hacer de esa forma. Lo normal sería tener dos métodos, uno con el `@RequestMapping` asociado a archivo, y otro a documento. Si es por no repetir código porque los dos métodos sean muy parecidos, lo que puedes hacer es un método privado con toda la lógica y que cada uno de estos métodos con `@RequestMapping` llamen al privado con un parámetro que te ayude a discriminar el tipo.

Comment: 1 metodo del controle solo hace 1 metodo html no puedes tener 2 @RequestMapping(value = "/archivo/{loquesea}") eso necesita un metodo en el controler  @RequestMapping(value = "/documento/{loquesea}") eso necesita otro

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA los dos metodos son practicamente iguales , no tienen variaciones a la expcecion del content-type devuelto y ese parametro en la URL ( que no puedo cambiar ) de ahi que me gustaria tenerlo en un solo metodo , sin tener que sacar todo lo comun a un metodo privado.

Comment: Como buena practica no deberías tener 2 Request en el mismo método aun cuando sean muy similares, es mejor opción tener ese código en otro método, si en algún futuro te das cuenta que otro servicio necesita las misma cosas comunes pues solo lo instancias de nuevo, si es lógica de negocios difiero con @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA no deberías de tener lógica en un controller y de preferencia deberias usar un manager para que te resuelva consumiendo un service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Puedes probar si de esta forma te funciona?

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/archivo/{loquesea}", "/documento/{loquesea}" })
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getValores(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String loquesea)
    if (request.getContextPath().startsWith("/archivo")) {
        // Archivo
    } else if (request.getContextPath().startsWith("/documento")) {
        // Documento
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
objeto.getClass().getName()
```

Te dará el nombre de la clase que construyó el objeto.

Si es un archivo, el objeto archivo estará creado por una clase, si es un documento, el objeto documento estará creado por otra clase distinta.